# How to remove StartMenu shortcut using C#

Tags: c#, windows

How can I remove a shortcut folder from Startmenu in Windows using C#, I know how to do that using this code:

```
    private void RemoveShortCutFolder(string folder)
    {
        folder = folder.Replace("\"  ", "");
        folder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu), folder);
        try
        {
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.Delete(folder, true);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

But the problem that I need to remove one shortcut folder in ALL USERS folder, not the current logged user. Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu gives me the current user not all users folder.

Any idea,

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind a little Win32, you can use [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204.aspx).

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern bool SHGetSpecialFolderPath(IntPtr hwndOwner, StringBuilder lpszPath, CSIDL nFolder, bool fCreate);

enum CSIDL
{
  COMMON_STARTMENU = 0x0016,
  COMMON_PROGRAMS = 0x0017
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  StringBuilder allUsersStartMenu = new StringBuilder(255);
  SHGetSpecialFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero, allUsersStartMenu, CSIDL.COMMON_PROGRAMS, false);
  Console.WriteLine("All Users' Start Menu is in {0}", allUsersStartMenu.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu instead of StartMenu.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I found the answer:

```
    private void RemoveShortCutFolder(string folder)
    {
        folder = folder.Replace("\"  ", "");
        folder = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ALLUSERSPROFILE"), "Start Menu"), "Programs"), folder);
        try
        {
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.Delete(folder, true);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Happy crashing on non-English systems. You may get away with this on Vista, but definitely not on XP. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this correctly either :-/

Comment: I was almost thinking of down-voting this. It won't work correctly in many situations (localized Windows versions being only one of them).